# Are Explorers affected by Worker Miasma Immunity?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Since Explorers can embark on Expeditions, and therefore spend turns inside a miasma tile for multiple turns, it would make sense that they should be affected by the worker miasma immunity granted by alien biology.

I would figure this out on my own, but exited the multiplayer game I was in before I could test this.

Comment: Did you mean "Since Explorers can embark on Expeditions"?

Comment: @SimonW yes. thanks. updated! I posted this late at night :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Technology "Alien Biology" only confers Miasma Immunity to Workers.

http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Biology_%28CivBE%29

In my current game I have recently researched this tech, and my Explorers still take damage from Miasma even when they are performing Expeditions.

Answer (score 0):

Alien Biology only confirs Miasma immunity to workers. However, it gives you 1 affinity for Harmony, which gives your explorers immunity. That is to say, workers can only get immunity through that specific tech, but explores get it through any tech which gives you harmony affinity.

This is true regardless of what your primary affinity is, or which ending you are going for.